# Docker-Compose ConnectionTimeoutError and then an ENOTFOUND error:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I am using Docker-Compose to start a couple of docker containers. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "2"
services:
  redisdb:
    #name: nowce-developdb
    image: redis:4.0.11-alpine
    volumes:
     - ../database/redis/provider/${PROVIDER_ID}:/data
    ports:
     - "${REDIS_PORT}:26379"
    restart: unless-stopped

  service:
    image: node:16.19-alpine
    #restart: always
    working_dir: /home/node
    entrypoint: "node ./app/app.js --env production"
    mem_limit: "300M"
    memswap_limit: "1G"
    ports:
     - "${APP_PORT}:13001"
    volumes:
     - .:/home/node # modified here to take into account the new app path
    # - ./logs:/home/app/logs
    user: node
    links:
     - redisdb
    restart: unless-stopped

    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
     - AES=false
     - SERVICE_ROUTE=develop
     - PROVIDER_ID=${PROVIDER_ID}
     - PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN=${PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN}
     - PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN_SUFFIX=${PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN_SUFFIX}
     - ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
     - ADMIN_EMAIL=${ADMIN_EMAIL}
     - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
     - PROVIDER_APIKEY=${PROVIDER_APIKEY}
     - INSTITUTION_CODE=${INSTITUTION_CODE}
     - CANDIDATE_URL=${CANDIDATE_URL}
     - CONTRIBUTOR_URL=${CONTRIBUTOR_URL}
```

I am looking at server-node and the docker containers for the node and the redis database seem to be working after running the command 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up'. Here is the output from the command 'docker ps':

```
20d1ff4ff6f7   node:16.19-alpine     "node ./app/app.js -…"   7 hours ago    Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:20000->13001/tcp             server-node-service-1 
23f859dcb07a   redis:4.0.11-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   27 hours ago   Up 6 seconds   6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20001->26379/tcp   server-node-redisdb-1
```

The database seems to load ok. There are some warnings about the ADMIN_USERNAME, ADMIN_EMAIL and ADMIN_PASSWORD variables not set so I am not sure if this is an issue. This is the output from the terminal:

```
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:C 06 Sep 22:20:05.242 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:C 06 Sep 22:20:05.243 # Redis version=4.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:C 06 Sep 22:20:05.243 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:M 06 Sep 22:20:05.248 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:M 06 Sep 22:20:05.248 # Server initialized
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:M 06 Sep 22:20:05.248 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:M 06 Sep 22:20:05.249 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:M 06 Sep 22:20:06.308 * DB loaded from disk: 1.059 seconds
server-node-redisdb-1  | 1:M 06 Sep 22:20:06.308 * Ready to accept connections
```

Here is the terminal showing the ENOTFOUND error:

```
server-node-service-1  | home:  /home/node/app/controllers/../../
server-node-service-1  | externalConfig.serviceConfig:  /service-config.json
server-node-service-1  | CONNECT WITH { host: 'server-node_redisdb_1', port: undefined }
server-node-service-1  | reindexing user exam!!!
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = put:/NowCEDevelop/exam/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator,panellist
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = get:/NowCEDevelop/exam/duplicate, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator,panellist
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/examBlueprint/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/examBlueprintQuota/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/question/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator,panellist
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/help/save, roles = super_admin
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/clinicalExam/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,clinical_actor,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/circuit/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/item/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/answerFormat/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | checkUserRoleSecurity(); config key = post:/NowCEDevelop/station/save, roles = super_admin,senior_lead,author,editor,reviewer,media_admin,clinical_lead_examiner,admin_team_member,duty_exam_administrator
server-node-service-1  | listening on port:  13001 Config {
server-node-service-1  |   environment: 'production',
server-node-service-1  |   copyright: '2022 Roundpoint Ltd',
server-node-service-1  |   version: '00.92.116',
server-node-service-1  |   serviceConfig: {
server-node-service-1  |     name: 'NowCE Configuration',
server-node-service-1  |     enableCORS: false,
server-node-service-1  |     acceptedProtocols: [ 'https', 'http' ],
server-node-service-1  |     host: '127.0.0.1',
server-node-service-1  |     port: 13001,
server-node-service-1  |     logging: {
server-node-service-1  |       fileNamePattern: 'service-<date>.log',
server-node-service-1  |       dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
server-node-service-1  |       refresh: 30000,
server-node-service-1  |       logDirectory: '/home/node/logs',
server-node-service-1  |       typeName: 'RollingFileAppender'
server-node-service-1  |     },
server-node-service-1  |     nohupLog: '/home/app/logs/nohup.log',
server-node-service-1  |     aws: {
server-node-service-1  |       accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
server-node-service-1  |       secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
server-node-service-1  |       s3bucket: 'nowce-cscm'
server-node-service-1  |     },
server-node-service-1  |     dockerhost: '127.0.0.1',
server-node-service-1  |     routes: {
server-node-service-1  |       redisport: '26379',
server-node-service-1  |       identity: [Object],
server-node-service-1  |       test: [Object],
server-node-service-1  |       develop: [Object],
server-node-service-1  |       staging: [Object],
server-node-service-1  |       prod100: [Object]
server-node-service-1  |     }
server-node-service-1  |   },
server-node-service-1  |   name: 'nowce-develop-<port>',
server-node-service-1  |   redisconf: { host: 'server-node_redisdb_1', port: undefined },
server-node-service-1  |   mysqlconf: undefined,
server-node-service-1  |   aws: {
server-node-service-1  |     accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
server-node-service-1  |     secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
server-node-service-1  |     s3bucket: 'nowce-cscm'
server-node-service-1  |   },
server-node-service-1  |   appkey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
server-node-service-1  |   includeXAPIKey: true,
server-node-service-1  |   enableCORS: false,
server-node-service-1  |   acceptedProtocols: [ 'https', 'http' ],
server-node-service-1  |   apptitle: 'NowCE Data Service',
server-node-service-1  |   baseURI: '/NowCEDevelop',
server-node-service-1  |   port: 13001,
server-node-service-1  |   threadIdleSeconds: 900,
server-node-service-1  |   readLoggerConfig: [Function (anonymous)]
server-node-service-1  | }
server-node-service-1  | **** App started ****
server-node-service-1  | 2023-09-06T22:22:25.975Z
server-node-service-1  | (node:1) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.
server-node-service-1  |
server-node-service-1  | Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
server-node-service-1  | For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
server-node-service-1  | (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
server-node-service-1  |
server-node-service-1  | node:internal/process/promises:279
server-node-service-1  |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
server-node-service-1  |             ^
server-node-service-1  |
server-node-service-1  | Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND server-node_redisdb_1
server-node-service-1  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)
server-node-service-1  | Emitted 'error' event on Commander instance at:
server-node-service-1  |     at RedisSocket.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:395:14)
server-node-service-1  |     at RedisSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
server-node-service-1  |     at RedisSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
server-node-service-1  |     at RedisSocket._RedisSocket_connect (/home/node/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:167:18)
server-node-service-1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
server-node-service-1  |   errno: -3008,
server-node-service-1  |   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
server-node-service-1  |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
server-node-service-1  |   hostname: 'server-node_redisdb_1'
server-node-service-1  | }
server-node-service-1  |
server-node-service-1 exited with code 0
```

Can anyone see why I am getting the error? I am fairly new to Docker-Compose and am at a loss as to where to look!

Many thanks.

EDIT:
I am adding the service-config.json file which is where the "server-node_redisdb_1" was set. I have changed it to "server-node-redisdb-1":

```
{
    "name":"NowCE Configuration",
    "enableCORS": false,
    "acceptedProtocols": [
        "https",
        "http"
    ],
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 13001,
    "logging": {
        "fileNamePattern": "service-<date>.log",
        "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        "refresh": 30000
    },
    "nohupLog": "/home/app/logs/nohup.log",
    "aws":{
        "accessKeyId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "secretAccessKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "s3bucket": "nowce-cscm"
    },
    "dockerhost":"127.0.0.1",
    "routes":{
        "redisport":"26379",
        "identity":{
            "baseURI":"/NowCEIdentity",
            "name":"nowce-identity-<port>",
            "ports": [ 3001, 3002 ],
            "redisconf":{
                "host":"identitydb",
                "port": 22401
            }
        },
        "test": {
            "baseURI":"/NowCETest",
            "name": "nocontainer",
            "ports":[ 13001 ],
            "redisconf": {
                "host":"nowce-testdb",
                "port":26399
            }
        },
        "develop":{
            "baseURI":"/NowCEDevelop",
            "name":"nowce-develop-<port>",
            "ports": [ 13990 ],
            "redisconf":{
                "host":"server-node-redisdb-1",
                "port": 26379
            }
        },
        "staging":{
            "baseURI":"/NowCEStaging",
            "name":"nowce-staging-<port>",
            "ports": [ 3011, 3012 ],
            "redisconf":{
                "host":"nowce-stagingdb",
                "port": 22403
            }
        },
        "prod100":{
            "baseURI":"/P100",
            "name":"nowce-p100-<port>",
            "alias":"some customer name",
            "ports": [ 3101, 3102 ],
            "redisconf":{
                "host":"nowce-prod100db",
                "port": 22500
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong `host` in you config. `docker ps` says `server-node-redisdb-1` and your config has `server-node_redisdb_1`. Also, the `port` in your config is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my original post and added the service-config.json file, which is where the server-node_redisdb_1 was initialised. I have now changed it to server-node-redisdb-1 but where do I check the port?

Comment: @Darren: The problem could be in your code or a missing value for an environment variable. It's difficult to know for sure but the log message `CONNECT WITH { host: 'server-node_redisdb_1', port: undefined }` doesn't look correct as the port is `undefined`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I am still getting that problem so I will have a play around and try and spot the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Darren: Good luck. One more thing, the `ports` in your `docker-compose.yml` should probably be `${REDIS_PORT}:6379` as you start the Redis instance with port `6379` and not `26379`. The first part of the `ports` mapping is the host port and the second part is the container port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I shall see if that makes any difference.